# $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \arccos k$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Compute $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \arccos k$.
My attempt :the sequence is strictly increasing and if I prove that it is not upper bounded its limit is $\infty$. However, I can't prove the last part.

Comment: Are you computing $\arccos 2$ with complex numbers?

Comment: What is $\arccos(10)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\cos^{-1}(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}+i\log(\sqrt{1-x^2}+ix)$$
So
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{i}\cos^{-1}(x)=\infty$$

Comment: Isn't arccos multivalued?

Comment: @N.S. Is it? I think it's up to your definition. Of course, $\cos^{-1}$ is formally not a function but a relation, but you can define an "arccos" function.

Answer (score 0):

Well, $\arccos(k)$ is not defined for $k\ge 1$ when we consider it as a real function. So the question only makes sense when we consider it as a complex function. Thus
$$
\cos ^{-1}(k)=\frac{\pi }{2}+i \log \left(\sqrt{1-k^2}+i k\right).
$$
Then obviously $\sum_{k \ge 1} \cos ^{-1}(k)$ does not converge.